# Complex numbers argument problem

Tags: complex-numbers

What would be the argument of $z$ if $z=2016-2016i$?

$i$ is iota. 
My try. The argument of $2016$ should be $zero$ as it lies on the positive x axis of argand plane. And the argument for $2016i$ should be $0$-$pi/2$=$pi/2$ since it lies on positive y axis of argand plane. Finally argument of $z$ should be -$pi/2$.

But the answer shown is -$pi/4$.Just the misprint or am I missing out on a concept? Would love to learn any concept related to it.

Comment: iota ($\iota$) and the imaginary unit ($i$) aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments do not add together! Where in the world did you get the idea that $$\arg(z)+\arg(w)=\arg(z+w)?!$$ If this were true, every complex number would have an argument of either $0$, $\pi/2$ or $-\pi/2$, since, for example, $1+4i$ should have an argument of $0$ (the argument of $1$) plus $\pi/2$ (argument of $4i$), which sums to $\pi/2$.

### I strongly suggest you re-read the chapter on arguments!

---

The argument of a number is the *angle* between the real axis and the number, so you can (by drawing) quickly see that the tan of the argument is simply the imaginary part, divided by the real part.

---

OK, I was a bit quick saying "Arguments do not add together". In fact, they do, but not while adding numbers. They add when you multiply numbers, so the correct equation would be

$$\arg(z)+\arg(w)=\arg(z\cdot w)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't believe I got this wrong. I knew it very well.Please upvote the post. Help me to 150 points.

Comment: @Zlatan I upvote questions that are good, not questions that have users who need rep. Also, please accept one of the answers if it is what you needed.

Comment: I voted negative because this equation is only valid when considering the $2\pi$ module:
$$ \arg(z) + \arg(w) \equiv \arg(z \cdot w) \quad (\mbox{mod } 2\pi) $$
All operations with $\arg$ should be modular $2\pi$ to keep all values in the same branch (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Identities

Answer (score 1):

The argument $\theta$ of a complex number $z=a+bi$ is given by $\theta=\arctan({\frac ba})$. However, as with trigonometric functions, this can have infinite values, two of which satisfy the domain $\theta \in (-\pi,\pi]$, so you need to make sure you're choosing the one which is appropriate for the quadrant the complex number is in.

In this case, $$\arg{(z)}=\arctan({\frac{-2016}{2016}})=\arctan(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{4}$$ as $\theta$ is in the fourth quadrant.

Comment: "The argument of a complex number $z=a+bi$ is $\arctan{\frac ba}$." Weeeel, almost. Remember, $\arg(z)\neq \arg(-z)$!

Comment: @5xum Okay, so I thought about your comment but I don't understand it. Why isn't it so? I wrote it in an alternative way – the way it's written in my book. Is that more accurate?

Comment: What is the argument of $-1-i$?

Comment: @5xum Thank you! I updated my answer to be much clearer (which my book unfortunately wasn't!)

Answer (score 0):

Treat the terms 2016 and 2016i as vectors, now do you see it is something in the IInd quadrant at $45^\circ$ ? You can't add arguments like scalars.